# How do I export all functions for common test only?

Tags: erlang, rebar, common-test

I have been trying to export all the functions in an erlang module for use in a common test SUITE, not an eunit module. So far it has not worked for me. I am using rebar to run the SUITE, and I came across this question (http://lists.basho.com/pipermail/rebar_lists.basho.com/2011-October/001141.html), which is essentially exactly what I want to do, but the method will not work for me.

I have also added `{plugins, [rebar_ct]}.` into rebar.config but it has made no difference. I should point out all my tests pass when I export the functions normally, but I want to avoid this.
Any help would be great thanks.

Answer (score 11):

The compiler will cause all functions in a module to be exported if you add this into it:

```
-compile(export_all).
```

Or you could do it based on defs, like:

```
-ifdef(EXPORTALL).
-compile(export_all).
-endif.
```

That will only export everything if you have `{d, 'EXPORTALL', true}` in your rebar config `erl_opts` setting, e.g. something like:

```
{erl_opts, [
    {d, 'EXPORTALL', true}
    ]}.
```

If that doesn't work, make sure you don't have `erl_opts` twice in your rebar config.

Comment: Thank you, it does work when I do that, but I want to avoid exporting everything as it is unnecessary and costly. I just want them exported when the test suite is calling them. Using a method like eunit test only export like below.
`-ifdef(EUNIT).`
`-compile(export_all).`
`-endif.`

Comment: `TEST` is defined for eunit, but I don't know off hand if it is defined for ct.

Comment: It is not defined for ct, so the next step is to define it in the config with `{d, 'TEST', true}` in erl_opts, but for some unknown reason to me, it will not work.

Comment: It's weird, `{d, 'TEST', true}` really should work, works for me, and the only time I just saved tearing my hair out because a def wasn't defined was when I had `erl_opts` twice. If you do `rebar eunit ct` does that work?

Comment: Nope no luck unfortunately, and I've only erl_opts defined once as well.

Comment: That's really weird. `rebar ct` doesn't compile the modules/app, but `eunit` does, if it hasn't previously been compiled for eunit, so I don't see how you're ending up without TEST defined when your ct suites are run. Another thing you can try is `rebar -DTEST clean compile ct`, which defines TEST, or `-DCT` if you want to distinguish eunit and ct.

Comment: Hi @liam_g, I understood when you say that "exporting everything is unnecessary". But, why is it expensive?

Answer (score 5):

with rebar3 you can define in the config file extra option for the compilation for common test:

```
{ct_compile_opts, []}.
```

her you can add export_all which will be available for common test only. not sure it exists for rebar.

Comment: After trying to add it in, unfortunately it doesn't appear to exist in rebar. Thanks though

Comment: Consider [rebar3](http://www.rebar3.org/) which is mostly backwards-compatible and has many improvements.